# $\forall \lambda \in \mathcal{F}: A x=\lambda x: \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ - Correct notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, notation, linear-transformations

I am new to formal mathematics, and thus not very experienced with correct notation. 
Consider $A\in End(V)$ where $V$ is a vector space over $\mathcal{F}$. I want to write $\sigma(A)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ more explicitly, also using symbols. Would this be correct:
$$
\forall \lambda \in \mathcal{F}: A x=\lambda x: \lambda \in \mathbb{R}
$$
In words, I want to say that all eigenvalues of $A$ are real.

Comment: Besides how to write $\sigma(A)$ using symbols, what is its definition in words? Without knowing that, I would not want to guess at a possible answer to your question.

Comment: $\sigma(A)$ denotes the spectrum of $A$, so I want to say that all eigenvalues of $A$ are in the reals.

Comment: $\forall \lambda \in \mathcal{F}:  (\exists x \in V\setminus \{0\}: A x=\lambda x) \implies \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this issue by starting with words and working towards symbols. Also, I would work with one portion at a time, starting by carefully expressing the spectrum of $A$ using set builder notation:

- The spectrum of $A$ is set of all elements of $\mathcal F$ that are eigenvalues of $A$.
- $\sigma(A)= \{\lambda \in \mathcal F : \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A \}$.
- $\sigma(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathcal F : \text{there exists $x \in V - \{0\}$ such that $Ax = \lambda x$} \}$
- $\sigma(A) = \{\lambda \in \mathcal F :  \exists x \in V - \{0\} \, \text{such that} \, Ax = \lambda x \}$

One could go further and replace the words "such that" with some symbols, if one truly desired.

Now to express that $\sigma(A) \subset \mathbb R$ you can just substitute

$\{\lambda \in \mathcal F :  \exists x \in V - \{0\} \, \text{such that} \, Ax = \lambda x \} \subset \mathbb R$

But, I have two followup thoughts:

1. The elements a general field $\mathcal F$ need not be real numbers, so this well expressed statement might be completely false. Of course, in some cases it becomes an interesting statement, particularly when $\mathcal F$ is the field of complex numbers.
2. I realize that you are more-or-less just trying to understand how to write good notation, but keep in mind that there are good and bad reasons to express things in notation. If I had to write this statement in a paper for purposes of communicating mathematics to a reader who is a human being, I would write "the eigenvalues of $A$ are real numbers".

Comment: Thank you very much. I see that my teacher sometimes use $|$ for 'such that' and other times he uses $:$ . Is there any difference between those two?

Comment: Another comment: shouldn't it be $\exists x\in V$ and not $\exists x\in A$?

Comment: I think it should be $\exists x \in V \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks for those corrections.

Comment: You did not define A and “such that” is not a formal expression.

Comment: Regarding "such that", no, there is really no difference, it just functions as a notational separator added to the very tersest expression of an existential quantifier: "$\exists x \, P(x)$" and "$\exists x : P(x)$ and "$\exists x \mid P(x)$" and "$\exists x$ such that $P(x)$" are all the same.

Comment: @WindSoul: In answering the OPs question, I am not restating things that were expressed clearly and correctly to begin with, e.g. I am not restating $A \in End(V)$.

Comment: I understand shortcuts and inferred sentencing, but using wording on a mathematical sentence defeats the purpose of formalism. You provided an answer that is upvoted and I ask why since is not correct. And instead of correcting it, you provide side reasoning instead. As for $$\exists x P(x)$$ is like saying “this that”. Is incorrect in any formalism